# Conditional Format Based on User Input

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, excel-2016

I am trying to use conditional formatting but I am running in to issues.

I have a single range which is populated based on user selection for an ActiveX ComboBox.  What I am trying to do is highlight rows if the single range of cells contains duplicate values, but if the cell is blank, contains the word "Value", or does not match another cell in the range then leave the cell and row as is.

Basically if Cell B4 equals B46 then highlight both rows.

I have tried the following formulas with no success.

```
=IF(AND($B$4:$B$50="",$B$4:$B$50="Value"),0,COUNTIF($B$4:$B$50,$B$4:$B$50,0))

=IF(AND($B$4:$B$50="",$B$4:$B$50="Value"),0,MATCH($B$4:$B$50:$B$4:$B$50,0))

=IF(AND($B$4:$B$50="",$B$4:$B$50="Value"),0,IF($B$4:$B$50=$B$4:$B$50,1,0))
```

I'm still learning excel and could use some help on this.  Thanks in advance!

Eric

Comment: Could you show some sample data and expected outcome? Be aware that with ranges of more than one cell you are working with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you want is a CF formula rule something like:

```
=AND(NOT(OR(B4="",B4="Value")),COUNTIF(B$4:B$50,B4)>1)
```

applied to B4:B50.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone who provided a response. I was able to develop a solution that worked based on your responses.  The following is the solution I used:

1.) Created a conditional format highlighting duplicate values.

2.) Created a conditional format using the below formula to highlight duplicate rows, ignore blank rows, and ignore rows with "Value" in cell B4:

```
  =AND(COUNTIF($B$4:$B$63,$B4)>1,LEN($B4)>0,LEN($B4)-4>0)
```

Thank you once again for everyone's assistance.

Eric